# Using REGEXP_REPLACE to transform accented letters into non accented counterparts

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm a student learning mysql, using MySQL Workbench.
I'd like to know the best way to translate accented vowels into non accented vowels.

I Used the following query

```
SELECT nome,apelido,servico_email, 
    concat(
            lcase(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(nome,'[àáâäã]','a'),'[éèêë]','e'),'[íìîï]','i'),'[óòôöõ]','o'),'[úùûü]','u')),
            ".", lcase(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(apelido,'[àáâäã]','a'),'[éèêë]','e'),'[íìîï]','i'),'[óòôöõ]','o'),'[úùûü]','u')), "@",
            servico_email
    ) AS 'email'
FROM dadosPessoais;
```

Which works but i'd like to know if there's a better way to do it, a shorter way to do it either with regexp_replace or any other command to transform

[àáâäãéèêëíìîïóòôöõúùûü]

directly into

'aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuu'